# AngularJS: How to render JSONP data into HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to the concept of $http and trying to retrieve data from different sites. My question is. How will I be able to render JSONP to HTML? In my $http, I am requesting Atari Wikipedia page. The page is displaying the content with HTML elements

" "

. How will I be able to render the data so that it will render properly?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    // $scope.list;
    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=atari&rawcontinue=true&action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      $scope.info = data.query.pages[2234].extract;
    }).error(function(data) {
      $scope.data = "Error";
    });

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DataCtrl">
    <div>{{info}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested to show the html then you could use `ng-bind-html` directive on the page to bind html from scope variable, but that too need `$sce.trustAsHtml` to make html sanitize. You also need to add `ngSanitize` module in your main app module with `angular-sanitize.js`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(info)"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    // $scope.list;
    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=atari&rawcontinue=true&action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
        $scope.info = data.query.pages[2234].extract;

    }).error(function(data) {
        $scope.data = "Error";
    });

    $scope.trustedHtml = function(val){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val)
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to pass it through the `$sce.trustAsHtml` function and display it using ng-bind-html:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DataCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$sce',function($scope,$http, $sce){
    // $scope.list;
    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=atari&rawcontinue=true&action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.info = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.query.pages[2234].extract);
    }).error(function(data){
        $scope.data = "Error";
    });

    }]);
```

.

```
 <div ng-bind-html="info"></div>
```

And don't forget to read the related [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-)

Without any additional checks this would make your system vulnerable. (XSS and similar things)

Comment: This worked out for me! I appreciate the help Lajos!

Answer (score 0):

The directive ng-bind-html works well as already was explained but it would be helpful just in order to displaying the data, if you want to manipulate in the controller the data, then you can use `$sanitize(html);`